# Vue.js dynamically rendering svg

Tags: javascript, svg, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to render a svg file containing Vue.js template syntax at specific places. The file gets rendered correctly.
Upon instantiation of the inner element (the svg), the template syntax gets replaced, but a vue warning is emitted:

```
vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

In the SVG there is a text containing the template syntax `{{data}}`

```
Vue.component('svg-show', {
    props: {
        model: {
            required: true
        },
        compiled:null
    },
    render: function (h) {
        return h("div",
            [
                h(this.compiled, {
                    props: {
                        data: this.model
                    }
                })
             ]);
    },
    created() {
        
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("mounted");
        console.log(this.model.SVG);
        this.compiled = Vue.compile("<div>" + model.SVG + "</div>");
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dg2hkeby/10/

i also tried to use a static variable for the data property, but this did not succeed either.

How would one achieve what i'm trying to do using Vue.js?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: added a jsfiddle

Comment: No offense but your code is super messy and incorrect in several places... Like... Why are you using `window.modal`? Why aren't you passing `window.modal` to the data? You're passing a non-existing `modal` variable to the `modal` value in the `data`, your Inkscape SVG should've been saved as Plain SVG not as Inkscape SVG...

Comment: Also you don't seem to be ever using the `modal.SVG` variable that you're assigning as your SVG, so how do you expect it to magically appear in the output?

Comment: the model is assigned dynamically. so is the model.SVG. since i can't provide dynamic loads of local files, i pasted the code of the svg in the model and assigned it there.

Comment: inside the component i'm rendering the svg code (containing template syntax in the text field) and compiling and rendering this. since i have to strip down the example, it is of course messy. and an inkscape svg is an svg just like any other svg, but for the sake of development ease, i'm using that. since i can embed the file and it works, it should work with loading that and having vue.js parse and refresh template syntax variables

Comment: also I am of course using the model.SVG variable that i'm assigning. i'm rendering a compiled component using the svg code inside my custom component svg-show